# Using i18n with Bootstrap-Rails and Simple_Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, internationalization, simple-form, rails-i18n

I have a Model named Variable scaffolded with name and description as variables. Its Index View is as follow:

```
<%- model_class = Variable -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize.titleize %></h1>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:id) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:name) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:description) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:created_at) %></th>
      <th><%=t '.actions', :default => t("helpers.actions") %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @variables.each do |variable| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to variable.id, variable_path(variable) %></td>
        <td><%= variable.name %></td>
        <td><%= variable.description %></td>
        <td><%=l variable.created_at %></td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                      edit_variable_path(variable), :class => 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %>
          <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                      variable_path(variable),
                      :method => :delete,
                      :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
                      :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")),
            new_variable_path,
            :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

So, it is a standart scaffold + Twitter_Bootstrap generated with Simple_form code.

I want to translate it to pt-BR and es but I really don't get it how to do it since it use the model_class.human_attribute_name(:name). The simple_form website says (let's say I'm translating to en):

```
en:
  simple_form:
    options:
      user:
        gender:
          male: 'Male'
          female: 'Female
```

That doesn't seen to work when I change "Options" to "attributes", "user" to "variables" and so on... To be honest, I don't even know if the translation should be placed inside the simple_form.pt_BR.yml or a new pt-BR file.

Any help, examples of i18n used in similar cases will be very appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single file for all your translations or split into several files, it doesn't matter.

I can suggest you to have a locale file for your own translations and don't modify simple_form (or other locales files if you use other gem). This way, if you update simple_form gem, you can use the new translations file without losing your own translations.

Your locale file should look like this :

```
es:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      variable:
        name: "Nombre"
        description: "Descripción"
```

Some precisions :

- The name of the model is in singular
- You should use 'labels' and not 'options'. 'Options' is for translating options in collection helpers

Hope this help.

Comment: I wasn't able to use simple_form's tag, but I followed your advice and created another locale file. The following code created the defaults I needed:
`pt-BR:
  attributes:
    name: "Nome"
    description: "Descrição"
    id: "Código"
``